# UsageStat list showing apps two times

Tags: android

i am creating an module which will show the app usage in list view with app icon , name , their usage time every thing is going really good but i don't know why every application is printing two times in list view..how can i resolve this please help. My code is this.

```
public class Tab_One_Fragment extends Fragment {

    Context context;
    List<UsageStatisticsModel> usageInfo;
    UsageStatisticsAdapter adapter;

    ListView listView;

    int mode;
    UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    int initial_value = 0;


    public Tab_One_Fragment(){
        //Required empty public constructor...
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE); //Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        // ** This line is for stop the rotation of screen ** //
        //getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);


        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_fragment , container , false);
        return view;
      }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        context     = view.getContext();
        usageInfo   = new ArrayList<UsageStatisticsModel>();
        listView    = (ListView)    view.findViewById(R.id.statistics_list_view);

        //checkPermission();

        show();
    }

    private void checkPermission(){

        AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        assert appOps != null;
        mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:get_usage_stats",
                android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName());
        boolean granted = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
        if(granted)
        {
            show();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


   private void show(){

       usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
       long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
       long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
       List<UsageStats> stats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, start, end);

       //List<UsageStats> stats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, System.currentTimeMillis()- TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),System.currentTimeMillis()+ TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));                       //start is from time in long
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

            List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            HashSet<ApplicationInfo> apps = new HashSet<>();

            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfos) {
                //apps.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo);

                if ((resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                    //............................
                } else {
                    apps.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                }
            }

            for (ApplicationInfo app : apps) {

                installedApps.add(app);
                String app_packageName = app.packageName;
                CharSequence LABEL = app.loadLabel(pm);
                Drawable ICON = app.loadIcon(pm);

                long totalTimeForeground = 0;

                for (UsageStats us : stats) {

                    if (!app_packageName.equals("com.pinigkidslauncher") && app_packageName.equals(us.getPackageName())) {                                  // here i'm getting time for apps other than 'myapp'

                        totalTimeForeground += us.getTotalTimeInForeground();// here you'll get total time used based on package

                    }

                }

                String Lab = LABEL.toString();
                long minutes = (totalTimeForeground / 1000)  / 60;

                int min = (int) minutes;
                showList(ICON , Lab , min);


            }

   }


   private void showList(Drawable _icon , String _label , final int _minutes) {

       final UsageStatisticsModel model = new UsageStatisticsModel();

       model.setUsageDrawable(_icon);
       model.setUsageName(_label);
       model.setUsageHour(_minutes);

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

               while (initial_value < _minutes){  // 1440 minutes = 24 hours
                   initial_value +=1;
                   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                           model.setProgressbar(initial_value);
                       }
                   });
               }
           }
       }).start();

       //model.setProgressbar(_minutes);

       usageInfo.add(model);


       Collections.sort(usageInfo, new Comparator<UsageStatisticsModel>(){
           public int compare(UsageStatisticsModel obj1, UsageStatisticsModel obj2)
           {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return obj1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.name);
           }
       });

       adapter = new UsageStatisticsAdapter(context, usageInfo);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because show() method call two time  change as below

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    context     = view.getContext();
    usageInfo   = new ArrayList<UsageStatisticsModel>();
    listView    = (ListView)    view.findViewById(R.id.statistics_list_view);
    checkPermission();
    }
```